# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, jquery

As far as I can understand jQuery are conflicting. how can I solve the jQuery conlicts as for "bootstrap.min.js" "jquery.min.js" is needed.
Here is my code:

```
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="doctor.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `how can I solve the jQuery conlicts` declare only **once** each requiered libray on top of your page, ie: in header

Answer (score 2):

Use the `noConflict` Option. Check the attached snippet

```html
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>
    var jqOld = jQuery.noConflict();
    jqOld(function() {
        jqOld("#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    })
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="doctor.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input id = "datepicker"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you're loading two different versions of jQuery, `1.10.2` and `3.2.0`. Due to the order they are added to the page the second instance doesn't have the jQueryUI methods.

While it's possible to include multiple versions of jQuery in a page it should be avoided where possible as it's not a maintable solution. To fix the problem you should change your code to use a single instance of jQuery, like this:

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="doctor.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: After replacing by your code there is no error anymore but datepicker() is not working, i mean i am not seeing calendar type anything after clicking on text field.

Comment: It seems to work fine in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6jqqedtw/. Check the console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `var jquery_version = jQuery.noConflict()` after the jQuery script tag is loaded and use it later using jquery_version.
[jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: How is this relevant to the issue?

Comment: Web page is  including two jQuery version

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do that? At the moment this would seem to be half an answer

Comment: after `<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`
create `<script> var old_jquery = jQuery.noConflict() </script>`

move your

 `<script>
  // here you can use $ for jquery version 3.2.0 and old_jquery for 1.10.2 version
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>`

above to the </body> Tag.

Answer (score 0):

you attached two jquery files & 2 jquery ui files, remove one